# Prepared statement in Zend\Db\Sql not executing

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am experimenting with Zend\Db\Sql in zf2. I have some problems making a simple query. Below is my code.

```
$id = 342;
$select2 = $this->sql->select();
$select2->from('users');
$select2->where(array('fbid'=>$id));
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select2);
$result =  $statement->execute();
```

The statement above does not return any objects. May i know what is the problem with it?

Also, i have some doubts regarding prepared statements in zend db. Is prepared statements the correct and best way to make a query via Zend? I read from the web and it says it is well protected against sql injections.

Appreciate any help to guide me along.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to it.

Two more lines of code needed.

```
$resultSet = new ResultSet();
$resultSet->initialize($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, but the two lines of code that Slay suggested need one more.

```
$resultSet = new ResultSet();
$resultSet->initialize($result);   
return $resultSet->toArray();
```